# Install Magento SMTP Pro Email Extension in 2.04

Tags: magento2, extensions, email, smtp

I've tried to install the extension using these instructions but it doesn't appear to work.

> http://www.aschroder.com/2010/05/installing-a-magento-extension-manually-via-ftp-or-ssh/

GIT repo: https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension

I've also read that magento connect is not exactly stable for `magento 2.x`. I myself can't even sync my purchases successfully. So I'm hoping you can point me to or provide some installation instructions for `version 2.04`.

Comment: This module is for Magento 1

Answer (score 1):

That extension is not intended to work in Magento2. Try to either set a mailing system in your server or install another SMTP extension actually intended for Magento2 as opposed to its first version.